# Filtrar columna para obtener resultados no duplicados

Tags: sql

Estoy necesitando filtrar la siguiente tabla:

```
key(varchar(15)     fecha (datetime)
    35753           2019-02-13 08:47:51.210
    35753           2019-02-13 08:47:51.210
    45540           2019-02-13 09:02:44.230
    35753           2019-02-13 08:40:33.280
    45540           2019-02-13 09:02:44.230
    35753           2019-02-13 08:40:33.280
    35753           2019-02-13 08:41:43.143
    35753           2019-02-13 08:41:43.143
    35753           2019-02-13 08:39:59.943
    35753           2019-02-13 08:39:59.943
    35753           2019-02-13 08:42:42.090
    35753           2019-02-13 08:42:42.090
```

Lo que requiero es tener algo como:

```
35753   2019-02-13 08:47:51.210
45540   2019-02-13 09:02:44.230
```

Pero no se como realizar la consulta en `SQL` para que me genere entregue la tabla filtrada, eliminando los `key` repetidos y dejando solo el `key` con fecha mas actual para cada `DISTINCT key`.

¿Cómo puedo realizar la consulta que me genere estos resultados esperados?

Comment: Deberias de agregar la estructura de tu tabla.

Comment: Agrega un GROUP BY por la primera columna

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es quitar los repetidos?

Comment: si, lo he hecho, pero eso solo me ordena la tabla, lo que estoy necesitando es que la consulta verifique las primera columna (key) y mire su fecha de registro, y con esto solo me muestre los key con la fecha mas actual, en cierto modo seria hacer algo similar a un TOP 1, pero con cada key

Comment: si diego, eso busco

Comment: me parece interesante el group by, como lo podria hacer

Comment: Pues todo eso deberías añadirlo a la pregunta original, generalmente se reciben respuestas con una calidad proporcional a la pregunta. Si faltan datos faltará precisión en la respuesta.

Comment: gracias por tu aporte fly, como me aconsejas, he modificado la pregunta para que sea un poco mas precisa.

Comment: Los repetidos se quitan poniendo DISTINCT, pero eso no es lo que muestras en "lo que requiero es..."

Comment: si Fly, tienes razon, no habia expresado bien mi pregunta, conforme a tu sugerencia la edite para exponer mejor mi caso, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Bueno el group by lo ordena por cada registro de la columna que escojas. Pero si lo que quieres el el mas actual puedes usar el max() y ordernar con group by. Ejemplo: select max(columnafecha) from tabla group by columna 1

Comment: @WilliamRodriguez bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Para futuras preguntas, puedes leer: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza esto:

```
select key, max(fecha) 
from nombreTabla group by key
```

Utilicé una tabla igual a la de la pregunta, agregando varios datos iguales y me funcionó.

```
Con esta tabla:
id   key         fecha
1   1234    2019-02-13 09:23:50.703
2   1235    2019-02-13 10:23:52.610
3   1236    2019-02-13 10:23:54.920
4   1234    2019-02-13 10:23:56.790
5   1234    2019-02-13 11:24:09.333
```

Y me da de resultado esto:

```
 key        fecha
1234    2019-02-13 11:24:09.333
1235    2019-02-13 10:23:52.610
1236    2019-02-13 10:23:54.920
```

Answer (score 3):

Según tu edición actual creo que lo que buscas es:

```
SELECT key, max(fecha) 
  FROM tabla 
 GROUP BY key
```